# How to insert \ell in text box on figure in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a plot in matlab and want to insert a text box write inside ell symbol. Till now i couldn't do it. I wrote '\ell','interpreter','latex' but it doesn't accept. I appreciate If anyone could help. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Do you really need to do it in Matlab, or can you afford other options? If so, I may have suggestions. BTW, I really like the fabric

Comment: I need to insert it into Matlab figure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you may do it;

```
plot([0 2 1]);
text(2,1,'$\ell$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',30);
```

[image]